# Angular 4- *ngFor not functioning on Array of Objects

Tags: angular

I have some problems in looping at the html side using *ngFor on the data received from the REST service below is what i am doing:

```
  getQuestionaire(type: String) {
    const url = `${this.questionaireTypeUrl}/${type}`;
    return this.http.get(url).map(
      (response: Response) => {const questioniares: any[] = response.json();
        return questioniares;
      }
    );
  }
```

Here i call the function in one of the app.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
    .subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.quesType = params['type'];
        this.questionaireService.getQuestionaire(this.quesType).subscribe(
          (questionaires: any[]) => {
            this.questionaire = questionaires;
            console.log(this.questionaire);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Here i am looping using *ngFor on the html side and creating a table dynamically

```html
<table class="table ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="active">QUESTIONAIRE NAME</th>
          <th class="active">LEVEL</th>
          <th class="active">LAST MODIFIED</th>
          <th class="active">PUBLISHED BY</th>
          <th class="active">VALIDITY DATE</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngFor="let questionaireEl of questionaire">
        <tr>
          <td>{{ questioniareEl.nameQuestionaire }}</td>
          <td>{{ questionaireEl.levelQuestionaire }}</td>
          <td>{{ questionaireEl.lastUser }}</td>
          <td>{{ questionaireEl.publishingUser }}</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
 </table>
```

**Problem:** The console logs the data i am looping on it consists of an array of objects and i can't figure out how could i access the elements i need to display please help!!

[image]

Comment: Can you show the json response from the server?

Comment: Do you need an `| async` there?

Comment: can you try with `{{ questioniareEl?.nameQuestionaire }}` ?

Comment: Is questioniares declared with empty array in the class definition? If not set it to [].

Comment: @match both solution i have tried and they worked...But i would like to know the role of the wild card operator ?

Comment: @micronyks both solution i have tried and they worked...But i would like to know the role of the wild card operator ?

Comment: @AdnanAbdulKhaliq https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Answer (score 1):

You need to use async pipe `<tr *ngFor="let questionaireEl of questionaire | async">...`

Or you can write

```
<td>{{ questioniareEl?.nameQuestionaire }}</td>
<td>{{ questionaireEl?.levelQuestionaire }}</td>
...
```

to avoid that error

Comment: Yes it solved for me thank you! But i would like to know the role of the wild card operator ?

Comment: This operator prevent evaluating of expression, if object before '?' has null/undefined value. That avoid exception and not break your app

Answer (score 1):

Here `?.` comes to rescue

*generally when async call happens, you exactly don't know when would result come/arrive to the template. But other hand, template would get parsed to HTML and it would want to display the data that **have not yet arrived** from the async call.
 So until data comes back, `?.` operator would wait (& would not throw any template error). 

once data arrives, `?.` operator allows to print the arrived data.*

eg.

```
{{questioniareEl?.nameQuestionaire}}
```